# How to limit number of records on right side of join using activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, limit

I want to list all the users in the database.  For each user I also want to show the 3 top images in that user's gallery.  I want to avoid making a separate query for each user to get the user's top 3 images.

Is there an activerecord-y way of doing this that doesn't require dropping down into SQL specific syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can use include. If rails 2:

```
User.find(:all, :include => :images)
```

Rails 3

```
User.include(:images)
```

Now you have images for all your uses in a single query for each user.

Comment: But wont that give me essentially ALL the images for all the users?  I only need the top 3 from each user.  Is there a way to limit the image results per user?